# Count several fields and group by inside three related tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been working with a query that needs to count items of different combinations in a group of related tables.

The structures are:

```
imageviews
----------
-imageId
-productId
-time
-browser
-os

clicks
------
clickId
imageId
time

downloads
---------
downloadId
clickId
time
```

If I use Eloquent with eager loading and group by two fields, I can see the relation 'click,' but I can't count the results of each combination of each pair of 'browser' and 'os'.

```
>>> $deliveries = App\Delivery::with('clicks')->groupBy('browser','os')->get();
```

I was trying to aggregate the counts with a query using Eloquent but with no successful results. For example, I have added the three models (Imageview, Click, Downloads) where I define the relations.

ImageView.php

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ImageView extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'imageId';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['imageId', 'product_id', 'time', 'browser', 'os', 'site'];


    public function clicks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Click::class, 'imageId', 'imageId');
    }
}
```

Click.php

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Click extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'clickId';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['deliveryId', 'clickId', 'time'];

    public function imageview()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\ImageView::class, 'imageId', 'imageId');
    }

    public function downloads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Install::class, 'clickId', 'clickId');
    }
}
```

Download.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Download extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['downloadId', 'clickId', 'time'];

    public function click()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Install::class, 'clickId', 'clickId');
    }
}
```

My goal is to build JSON that generates a result like this:

```
{
    "interval": {
        "start": "2018-01-07T14:30:00+0000",
        "end": "2018-01-07T18:20:00+0000" },
    "data": [ {
        "fields": {
            "browser": "Chrome", 
            "os": "Android"
        }, "stats": {
           "imageviews": 10,
           "clicks": 4,
           "downloads": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "browser": "Safari",
            "os": "iOS"
         },
         "stats": {
            "imageviews": 2,
            "clicks": 1,
            "downloads": 1
         }
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "browser": "Chrome", 
            "os": "iOS"
        }
        "stats": {
           "imageviews": 15,
           "clicks": 5,
           "downloads": 3
        } }
    ]
}
```

How can I get this? I'm happy to provide additional info if needed.